# Number Guessing Game in c#

Tags: c#, .net

I'm working on Visual Studio about binary search in c#. My project about the computer find the user's guess number. So, I use tihs code in the main;

```
        int min = 0;    // minimum number in the array
        int max = 100;    // maximum number in the array
        int middle = 50;  // middle number in the array
        int counter = 1;
        string name, input;
        int guess_number;

        Console.WriteLine("Hello, this is a game that finding the number of in your mind. If you want to play so let me know you! ");
        name = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Awesome welcome to the game " + name + " guess a number between " + min + " and " + max + " Please! ");
        Console.WriteLine("Is your guess " + middle + " ?\nIf it's your guess then write (0) please!\nIf it's too high then write (1) please!\nIf it's too low then write (2) please!");
        input = Console.ReadLine();
        guess_number = Convert.ToInt32(input);
        Console.WriteLine(" You select " + guess_number + " so, ");

        do
        {
            counter += 1;

            if (guess_number == 2)
            {
                min = middle + 1;
            }
            else if (guess_number == 1)
            {
                max = middle - 1;
            }
            else if (guess_number != 1 || guess_number != 2 || guess_number != 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(" Please write 0, 1 or 2 " + name);
            }
            middle = (min + max) / 2;
            Console.WriteLine("Is your guess " + middle + " ?\nIf it's your guess then write (0) please!\nIf it's too high then write (1) please!\nIf it's too low then write (2) please!");

            Console.WriteLine(counter + " times I tried for finding your number ");
        } while (guess_number != 0);

        Console.ReadKey();
```

However, output always repeat after the user write anything, why the reason about that, is there anyway to get the number?

Comment: Could you tell us your logic?

Comment: I mean, I want to take a number from the user (0,1,2) and find the number with binary search with computer.

Comment: This line:'else if (guess_number != 1 || guess_number != 2 || guess_number != 0)
' can be shortened to: 'else if (guess != 0)' because you have already checked if it's one or two.

Comment: Thank you Rup, I did it :) You Are Awesome!

Comment: Awe, thank you Poul I fixed that part too :) it helped a lot, You are Awesome

Comment: @PoulBak even more so this is a very common mistake with beginners. `1!=2` and `2!=1`...the correct operator to use would be `&&` and *not* `||`. However you are right this can be simplified to `!=0` since the `if` and `else if` already filter out those conditions.

Comment: Awe, I didn't see that too @Pinkfloyddx33, thank you, You are awesome :)

Answer (score 3):

from your description, I think you need to let user input new value to `guess_number` variable in the loop end otherwise the loop will not end from the condition `guess_number != 0`.

```
do
{
    counter += 1;
    if (guess_number == 2)
    {
        min = middle + 1;
    }
    else if (guess_number == 1)
    {
        max = middle - 1;
    }
    else if (guess_number != 1 || guess_number != 2 || guess_number != 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(" Please write 0, 1 or 2 " + name);
    }
    middle = (min + max) / 2;
    Console.WriteLine("Is your guess " + middle + " ?\nIf it's your guess then write (0) please!\nIf it's too high then write (1) please!\nIf it's too low then write (2) please!");

    Console.WriteLine(counter + " times I tried for finding your number ");

    input = Console.ReadLine();  // let user key in new value.
    guess_number = Convert.ToInt32(input);

} while (guess_number != 0);
```

Comment: I almost try this one :) thank you guys :) I worked on this so many hours :)

Comment: Thank you D-Shih, :) You Are Awesome!

Comment: @Alkyonemis No problem glad to help

Comment: `1!=2` and `2!=1`. Technically the second `else if` should be using `&&` and not `||`. However due to the `if` and the first `else if`, these conditions are already eliminated, thus the `!=0` just *happens* to perform the intended functionality. That said, it's probably worth correcting by either switching to the correct operators or simplifying to just `!=0`

Answer (score 2):

the last readKey should be inside the while.

```
do
        {
            counter += 1;

            if (guess_number == 2)
            {
                min = middle + 1;
            }
            else if (guess_number == 1)
            {
                max = middle - 1;
            }
            else if (guess_number != 1 || guess_number != 2 || guess_number != 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(" Please write 0, 1 or 2 " + name);
            }
            middle = (min + max) / 2;
            Console.WriteLine("Is your guess " + middle + " ?\nIf it's your guess then write (0) please!\nIf it's too high then write (1) please!\nIf it's too low then write (2) please!");

            input = Console.ReadLine();
            guess_number = Convert.ToInt32(input);

            Console.WriteLine(counter + " times I tried for finding your number ");
        } while (guess_number != 0);
```

Comment: Yes, I tried it but after the user enter one number then, it doesn't say "You select 2 so," bla bla... Also, if the user write 9 then it confused..

Comment: Thank you for helping n1989, you are Awesome :)